# Script is loaded from Live Server but not when opening index.html

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I am new to JS. I made a simple Snake game using vanilla JS in VS Code. There is minimal CSS in the code so I put that in the html.

When I open the **index.html** from VS Code with Live Server (`http://127.0.0.1:5500/`) it works fine.

But when I open it from the file explorer (`file:///D:/Prog/Javascript/VanillaJS_projects/Snake/index.html`) only the html gets loaded, no Snake and Food pieces appear. And the same happens if I try to open it with *htmlpreview.github.io*

This is the **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Snake</title>
    <script src="game.js" defer type="module"></script>
    <style>
        ...
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="game-board"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't matter what browser I use, I get the same result.

What is the difference? Why won't it load properly?

Answer (score 0):

You browsers honor [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy#Default_content_security_policy).

If you open `file:///` URLs, you may think of your browser as a poor man's file viewer.